# Rust: "decombine" traits?

Tags: rust, traits

Suppose, I have a number of traits:

```rust
trait Device {}
trait Named {}
trait Report {}
```

I have a number of structs, some of which implement some subset of these traits, and then I have some logic that expects a type that implements all of them, say, I want to have a collection of devices that have names and can produce reports. To reduce the typing (on the keyboard), I create a combined trait:

```rust
pub trait ReportNamedDevice: Named + Device {}
impl<T: Named + Device> ReportNamedDevice for T {}
```

(`Report` is omitted for now until I can make the existing ones work)

And then I use a collection of those in a struct:

```rust
pub struct Room<'a> {
    pub name: String,
    pub devices: Vec<&'a dyn ReportNamedDevice>,
}
```

Now, the room itself is `Named`, and I want to be able to add it to a `House`. And I want all of my collections of `Named` things to contain things with unique names, so I write the following filter function:

```rust
fn name_is_in_named_vector(name: &String, haystack: &Vec<&dyn Named>) -> bool {
    haystack
        .iter()
        .map(|x| x.name().clone())
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
        .contains(name)
}
```

But when I try to use it in my `Room` impl, I get a `mismatched types` error, because the compiler doesn't treat `ReportNamedDevice` as `Named`:

```rust
impl<'a> Room<'a> {
    pub fn add_device(&mut self, device: &'a dyn ReportNamedDevice) {
        if !name_is_in_named_vector(device.name(), &self.devices) {
            self.devices.push(device)
        }
    }
}
```

I know I could replace the `haystack` type in the filter function, but I would like to be able to reuse it for filtering rooms as well.

Is there a way I can make this work?

Comment: `type ReportNamedDevice = dyn Named + Device`?

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't have to collect a new vec to find an element in another. Try using `Iterator`'s `find` method.

Comment: @PitaJ: I get `only auto traits can be used as additional traits in a trait object` for `+ Device`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a way, just use generics instead of trait objects, that works becaues while a `&dyn ReportNamedDevice` isn't the same as a `&dyn Named` it *does* implement `Named`:

```rust
fn name_is_in_named_vector<T: ?Sized + Named>(name: &str, haystack: &[&T]) -> bool {
    haystack
        .iter()
        .find(|x| x.name() == name)
        .is_some()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0bf8364225ce0f77cc453879fb002831)

<sub><sub>Note: I've applied [isaactfa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11423104/isaactfa)'s hint about `find` in the comments and the tips of [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference &String, &Vec, or &Box as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-string-vec-or-box-as-a-function)</sub></sub>

Comment: Thank you for the link to the article as well )